# what mysql function do I need if column1 matches a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm performing a select query and formatting the date column. In some cases the value in the database will be NULL and for those, I do not want to output `00/00/0000` (US Format mm/dd/yyyy). I thought COALESCE is what I would need but after further investigation, it is not. So, what am I looking for here?

I'm outputting in PHP so perhaps I should evaluate the output there instead of trying to do it in the query?

Comment: What value do you want in the case the date be `NULL`?

Comment: The displayed value could be either `--` just to show a result was returned or simply blank is also fine.

Comment: For others who come across this, I was mistaken thinking COALESCE was not what I needed because I had implemented it incorrectly. Turns out it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to do two things here:

- select your dates in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`
- select some placeholder value in case the dates might be NULL

We can use `DATE_FORMAT` here along with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(col, '%m/%d/%Y'), '--') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: Well, I had the date formatting right with `DATE_FORMAT(p.noticestartdate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS noticestartdate_formatted,` so for me implementation, I need to use `COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(p.noticestartdate, '%m/%d/%Y'),'--') AS noticestartdate_formatted,` trying now.

Comment: Works perfectly. I do not believe I would have figured this out tonight - thank you!

Comment: Just waiting on SO to let me do so :)  (2 min to go)